# Validation of 3-d type password using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have one password field that should have an alphabetical, numerical, one upper case and one special character with no spaces and minimum 8 characters length. How can I validate this using angular.js?
My code is below:

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" >
```

In some of my code I am using `ng-message` to check the validation like email and username.

Comment: Do you need specific error messge for specific error? Like : At least one number is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pattern and find proper regEx

```
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{6,6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}/.">
```

This is expamle regEx, u should find one that accept your criteria

Comment: @ Bleja : I need to know how to use this any example ?

Comment: I updated answer, if input value dont match ng-pattern it will be invalid. U can display message for this with <span ng-show="parentFrom.itemname.$indvalid">invalid user name</span> or show ng-messages

Comment: parentForm is name of form that contains this input

Comment: and u should not use hmlt validation, like type=email if u are using ng-pattern

Comment: and u need to add novalidate directive to form. <form name="urFrorm" novalidate></form